# How to Synchronize two tables on different sql servers by using Microsoft Sync Framework Programatically?

Tags: c#, sql-server, console-application, microsoft-sync-framework

I Have two Databases, One is on Local Server and another is on Web Server. Now i wnat to Synchronize these Databases. I want to Use Microsoft Sync Framework for it.
I found a Tutorial Here:-

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/2190.tutorial-synchronizing-sql-server-and-sql-server-compact-sync-framework.aspx

I Followed Steps But when i use DbSyncScopeDescription in my Main Method i got this Error:-

```
          The type or namespace name 'DbSyncTableDescription' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Can Anybody tell me Exact Procedure of doing Synchronizing sql server database or any working example?

Please Help me.

Thanks in Advancce........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might not have added reference to your project. You need to add

```
Microsoft.Synchronization.Data.dll
Microsoft.Synchronization.Data.Server.dll
Microsoft.Synchronization.Data.SqlServer.dll
```

These assemblies to your project

Comment: i Added Them. Still this error is coming... I says me to generate class for it. Do i need to do it or not? If Yes, Than what should i write in this class.

Comment: No.You don't need to add class. I also got this error but I just added these dll from this path C:\Program Files\Microsoft Sync Framework\2.1\Runtime\ADO.NET\V3.1\x86

Comment: i added it from C:\Program Files\Microsoft Sync Framework\2.1\Runtime\x86. Should i remove them and add it from anotherplace?

Comment: yeah. You need to remove those dlls.

Comment: You were right. I added them from .Net component and My Problem is Solved. Thanks for tha Answer....

Comment: Thanks !!! its also work for me. after explicitly reference those two dll